# UIactionsheet issue on UITab Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uitabbar, uiactionsheet

I am new to ios. I have implemented a pp in which there is a tab bar.

Now in one of the tab i have implemented Action sheet.

I have added action sheet by

```
[actionSheet showFromRect:[self.view bounds] inView:self.view  animated:YES];
```

But by using this because of tab bar it is taking event on the tab bar.

Than i implemented it by following command

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

By this the previous problems solved but Now it stops animated.

What to do.

Thanks for Help

Comment: The documentation for `showFromTabBar:` states that the action sheet will be animated.

Comment: I get animation when I use [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.tabBarController.view];
```

Comment: Gives a warning "Instance method '-showinview' not found (return type defaults to id)